# Implementation class is causing "Duplicate class error

Tags: java, aem

I'm working on an AEM website and I'm trying to test implementing [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/aem-populate-a-drop-down-with-a-data-source-edafada90cc4) in my local AEM but I keep getting a "duplicate class" error on "StaticDataSourceModel".  If I comment out the implementation class the project builds fine.  Not sure what's causing this error.  There is no other class with the same name I've done a search with my IDE and also tried renaming the class several times but it always gives this error when the implementation class is there.

My code:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

public interface StaticDataSourceModel {
    @PostConstruct
    void init();
}
```

and the implementation class:

```
import com.client.wcm.diagnostics.core.models.StaticDataSourceModel;
import com.client.wcm.diagnostics.core.services.DataSourceService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.OSGiService;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.Self;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Model(
        adaptables = {SlingHttpServletRequest.class},
        adapters = {StaticDataSourceModel.class}
)
@Component
@Slf4j
public class StaticDataSourceModelImpl implements StaticDataSourceModel {

    @OSGiService
    private DataSourceService dataSourceService;

    @Self
    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        request = dataSourceService.getDataFromSource(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u checked all your package-info ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that @AmeeshTrikha?

Comment: Can u share screenshot of hierarchy of ur packages, showing file names